# Deleted file's name still remains in start menu

Tags: windows-7, windows

Hi i just deleted an old version of adwcleaner and installed  a new one
however the name for it still shows up in the start menu as adwclener5114.exe
adwcleaner5112.exe  and many others when i clicked on it it says windows
cannot find the item dragging it into desktop and pinning it shows the same error
please help!

Comment: Right click on the obsolete entry and select Delete.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please don`t delete the installations. Uninstall them. This will save you a lot of trouble(Trust me I have gone thorough it.)
Most probably the root cause is as you have just deleted the installation folder but have not cleaned up start menu folder.

Right click on the file in start menu and choose explore. You will see shortcuts for this file. just delete those shortcuts for unwanted files and it should work.

Also if possible run registry cleaner and clean out your registry for any unwanted entries for this application.

One **short solution** is install the same program again at same location and uninstall it. This should do all the work for you assuming you don`t have any other version installed(if any other version is installed then uninstall it first before installing this version).